# How to remove the extra blank line when using TikZ in algorithm2e?

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithm2e

I want to remove the blank in line 13. However it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
       \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,black]
        ($(#3)!(#1.north)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --
        ($(#3)!(#2.south)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
        node [align=center, text width=2.5cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering \caption{Algorithm} \vspace{.1in}
\begin{tabular}{p{15cm}}
\hline
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\KwIn{$R$.}
\KwOut{the optimal solution.}
\textbf{Setup:} Set the iteration number $r=0$.\tikzmark{right}\\
\For{$r=0$ to $R-1$} {
\tikzmark{top}
  \For{$j=1$ to $n$}
  {
    \For{$t=1$ to $h$}
{
Compute $P_{1}$\\
\If{$a<b$}
{
   break
}
\If{$a==b$}
{
Include solution
}
}
\tikzmark{bottom}}
} 
Return solution\\
\end{algorithm}
\\[-12pt] \hline
\AddNote{top}{bottom}{right}{Stage 1}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please note that there is a library called `tikzmark` which has an advanced version of your `\tikzmark` command.

Comment: \tikz[overlay]{} should be equivalent to \hbox{}.  You cannot see it, but it is still there.  The surprising thing is that it worked at all.

Comment: You can use `\vskip-10pt\rlap{\tikzmark{bottom}}}%`.  The `\rlap` does not leave vmode, but it sill adds vertical space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I use it and it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: @marmot You mean use tikzmark to replace \tikzmark in the line?

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure it solves the problem. `tikzmark` has a special sub-library for codes but AFAIK for `listings`, not `algorithm2e`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: @siracusa Why don't ask John to add an answer instead of closing?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Please add an answer, it seems Interesting to me.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I usually do that when the person might not be aware that their suggestion solved the issue, which wasn't the case here. Also this seems to be a quite common habit on this site. I'm sorry if it was considered impolite.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - It seems a bit much to add a solution for a large MWE when all it takes is a one-line patch (even if I did test it first).

Comment: @JohnKormylo The question is already closed, anyway